# Sustained communication over SSH in shell script

Tags: shell, ssh, zsh

I'm writing a zsh script in which I want to establish an SSH connection, send some commands to the remote host and read the output.

I could do something like

```
cat commands.list | ssh foobar.com | { process output }
```

However, that would execute in one shot and the connection will close. Instead I want to do something like -

```
while [ some condition ]; do
    write command to ssh process
    read output from ssh process
    make some decision about the next command to write to ssh process
do
```

I've looked at [zsh redirection](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) and [zsh process substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution) but haven't been able to figure out how exactly to use those to my advantage here.

There's a <(..) form of process substitution for reading and a >(..) form for writing but no form where I could read and write both. If there were one I could may be tie the process to custom file descriptors?

I also tried tying the stdin and stdout of the ssh process to two fifos (pipes), but writing (using echo) to the stdin pipe also sends an EOF (when echo process ends), closing the connection after executing the one command that was written

Any ideas if/how I could achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks.

Comment: A few options: `coproc ssh -tt foobar.com` (read about the `coproc` modifier in `man zshmisc`), copy a script to the remote host and execute it there, or use the `-M` option of `ssh` to set up a master `ssh` session; it will authenticate once and allow subsequent `ssh` sessions to share that channel, greatly speeding startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks chepner for your comment.

I also found the ControlMaster feature of ssh. 
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/speed-multiple-ssh-connections-same-server

Configured that in my config file and I don't mind running ssh again for each remote command!